# Build hint that allows you to specify the iOS build

Tags: codenameone

What is the build hint that allows you to specify the iOS build number in order to make two uploads with the same version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make two uploads with the same build number. Builds must have a different version number otherwise it will be blocked from uploading.

Comment: Thank Shai, I need to decrease the compilation version on the store. The App Loader don´t permit it. For example, On the App Store I uploaded the version 4.21 and I need to upload the 3.0 versión.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, I think Apple blocks those things.